# VSCode not importing "Text" and "Image" modules in React

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Components in my `./src/components` folder are imported by VSCode's refactoring keyboard shortcut e.g a component exported from `./src/components/Card/index.tsx` will bring up the option in VSCode: "Import 'Card' from module `components/Card`" when used in a `.tsx` file. All my components work this way except for two components the "Text", and "Image" components respectively. Are these some kind of reserved name in VSCode that's preventing the automatic addition of the import? Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `Text` and `Image` are built-in global objects already, so VSCode doesn't care to provide an option to auto-import.

Below is a playground showing these global objects (clearly defined already):

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CoUwHgLgsAUA9HAegflgSQLYEMDmJYIpA)